# Addressing individual content control nested inside repeating section content control

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following table.

[image: word]

Each cell represents an individual plain text context control. The entire row is then wrapped in a Repeating Section Context Control ("RSCC") which is tagged "ENTRY". As you know, I can add rows like this:

```
Sub MACRO1()
'
' MACRO1 Macro
'

Dim anchor_cc As ContentControl

Set anchor_cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ENTRY").Item(1)

' Add one more row
total = 1
For counter = 1 To total
    With anchor_cc
        .AllowInsertDeleteSection = True
        .RepeatingSectionItems(1).InsertItemAfter
    End With
Next counter

End Sub
```

I can also address an *INDIVIDUAL* RSCC like this, which will output the text contents of the ***entire row*** in a dialogbox:

```
Sub MACRO2()
Dim anchor_cc As ContentControl

Set anchor_cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ENTRY").Item(1)

With anchor_cc
    For counter = 1 To .RepeatingSectionItems.Count
        MsgBox (.RepeatingSectionItems(counter).Range)
    Next counter
End With

End Sub
```

How do I address an individual cell in that RSCC? For example, let's say I want to address the first cell in the first row. It's easy enough to address the first row. I can just set `.RepeatingSectionItems` index to 1, i.e.,

`.RepeatingSectionItems(1)`

How do I access the first cell in that row? Or the *nth* cell? Remember that the cells are individual plain text context controls. I don't know if that changes the answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't use `.RepeatingSectionItems` property which I believe comes with Word 2013 or 2016 (at this moment I'm in front of MS Word 2010).

Try with this logic to refer first row (where you could use your techinque) and next refer required cell in this row quite simply:

```
Dim ccEntry As ContentControl
Set ccEntry = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("ENTRY")(1)

'to get row...
Dim tblRow As Row
Set tblRow = ccEntry.Range.Tables(1).Rows(ccEntry.Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber))

'get first cell
Dim tblCell As Cell
Set tblCell = tblRow.Cells(1)
    Debug.Print tblCell.Range.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

If each cell in row is ContentControl object, then use this code (f.e. For cell in first row, second column):

```
RepeatingSectionItems(1).Range.ContentControls(2).Range.Text
```